# How could I use a number incrementor to show a specific amount of images in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to connect dice png files in a window, but I can not seem to connect the number incrementor that goes up to 10(for 10 images) to align with the said amount of dice. Is there a way to connect them?

This is a define function(firstDicePage()). Asks for the amount of dice you want to roll.

```
     # enables and disables the minus and plus button

    def changeMinusState():
               if (btn2['state'] == NORMAL):
                       btn2['state'] = DISABLED
               else:
                    btn2['state'] = NORMAL  

    def changePlusState():
            if (btn1['state'] == NORMAL):
                    btn1['state'] = DISABLED
            else:
                    btn1['state'] = NORMAL


    def increase():
            counter.set(min(10, counter.get() + 1))

    def decrease():
            counter.set(max(0, counter.get() - 1))



    lbl = Label(firstWindow, textvariable = counter, font='Helvetica 16 bold')
    lbl.place(x=450, y=330)

    btn1 = Button(firstWindow, text="+", font='Helvetica 16 bold',  padx = 8, pady = 5, command = increase, fg="dark green", bg = "white")
    btn1.place(x=499, y=320)

    btn2 = Button(firstWindow, text ="-", font='Helvetica 16 bold', padx = 11.1, pady = 5, command = decrease, fg="dark green", bg = "white")
    btn2.place(x=375, y=320)

    btn4 = Button(firstWindow, text = "Next", font='Helvetica 16 bold', command=lambda: secondDicePage())
    btn4.place(x = 800 , y = 530)

    btn5 = Button(firstWindow, text = "Select", font ='Helvetica 16 bold',  command = lambda: [changeMinusState(), changePlusState()], bg='#ffffff', 
                    activebackground = 'green', padx = 19, pady = 2) 
    btn5.place(x = 400, y = 385)
```

This define function connects to the first one. It has the dice.

Updated

```
def secondDicePage(num_dices):

    secondWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(window)  # Create new window.

    secondWindow.title("Dice Roller Generator")

    # Change Icon photo
    image = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\alexi\\Desktop\\Project Photos\\Dice logo.png")
    secondWindow.iconphoto(False, image)

    # Center 
    app_width = 900
    app_height = 600

    screen_width = secondWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = secondWindow.winfo_screenheight()

    x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
    y= (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

    secondWindow.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
```

images

```
    dice = ['dice_1.png', 'dice_2.png', 'dice_3.png', 'dice_4.png', 'dice_5.png', 'dice_6.png']

    # middle image
    img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\\Users\\alexi\\Desktop\\Project Photos\\questionmark.png"))


    lbl1 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl1.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl1.pack()
    lbl1.place(x = 380 , y = 95)

    lbl2 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl2.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl2.pack()
    lbl2.place(x = 195 , y = 95)

    lbl3 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl3.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl3.pack()
    lbl3.place(x = 565 , y = 95)

    lbl4 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl4.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl4.pack()
    lbl4.place(x = 746 , y = 95)

    lbl5 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl5.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl5.pack()
    lbl5.place(x = 1 , y = 95)

    lbl6 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl6.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl6.pack()
    lbl6.place(x = 380 , y = 300)

    lbl7 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl7.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl7.pack()
    lbl7.place(x = 195 , y =300)

    lbl8 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl8.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl8.pack()
    lbl8.place(x = 565 , y = 300)

    lbl9 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl9.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl9.pack()
    lbl9.place(x = 746 , y = 300)

    lbl10 = Label(secondWindow, image=img1)
    lbl10.img = img1  # Save reference to image.
    lbl10.pack()
    lbl10.place(x = 1 , y = 300)
```

Function for labels

```
    def rolling_dice1():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl1.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl1.image = image1

    def rolling_dice2():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl2.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl2.image = image1

    
    def rolling_dice3():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl3.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl3.image = image1


    def rolling_dice4():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl4.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl4.image = image1


    def rolling_dice5():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl5.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl5.image = image1

    
    def rolling_dice6():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl6.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl6.image = image1


    def rolling_dice7():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl7.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl7.image = image1

    def rolling_dice8():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl8.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl8.image = image1

    
    def rolling_dice9():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl9.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl9.image = image1

    
    def rolling_dice10():
            image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))

            lbl10.configure(image = image1, bg = '#B9C6C9')

            lbl10.image = image1
```

widgets

```
    btn1 = Button(secondWindow, text = "Back", font='Helvetica 16 bold', command = secondWindow.destroy)
    btn1.place(x = 30 , y = 530)

    btn2 = Button(secondWindow, text = "Roll Dice", font='Helvetica 16 bold', command = lambda: [rolling_dice1(), rolling_dice2(), rolling_dice3(), rolling_dice4(), rolling_dice5(), rolling_dice6(), rolling_dice7(), rolling_dice8(), 
                                                                                                    rolling_dice9(), rolling_dice10()])
    btn2.place(x = 400 , y = 30)
```

Comment: You can pass the value of `counter` to `secondDicePage()` and then create the required number of images inside `secondDicePage()`.

Comment: How could I start by passing the value? Could I use an if statement and have the condition be the def increase() that is inside the firstDicePage?

Comment: What I mean is that you pass the value of `counter` when `secondDicePage()` is executed: `command=lambda: secondDicePage(counter.get())`.  Of course you need to change the definition of `secondDicePage` to, for example, `def secondDicePage(num_dices)`.  Then inside `secondDicePage` function, you need to create the required number of images based on the passed value of `num_dices`.

Comment: I put the parameter inside the function and created all the required numbers of images, but I am unsure how exactly to base them on the passed value of num_dices.

Comment: It would be more easier to understand if you can add the updated code based on my suggestion.

Comment: sorry, I added it!